# git out of memory

Tags: git, rails

I went to my file directory, did

```
$ git init
$ git add
```

and then got

```
fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

One folder is maybe 2GB big because it is full of images.. the rest are very small. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

Your system don't have enough memory for to pack all the data in your repository into one file, which is git's default setting.

To work around this problem, set the `pack.packSizeLimit` configuration option to a value that is well within the available memory of your system..  You can set it with this command:

```
git config pack.packSizeLimit 1g
```

You can use the suffixes `g` for gigabytes, `m` for megabytes, or `k` for kilobytes.  Calling `git config` without any switches will set the setting just for this particular repository.  Use the `--global` switch to set it globally for your user account or `--system` for all user accounts on the machine (this option requires *root* access).